# Resizing OL3 features programmatically

Tags: openlayers-3

I have map with user drawn features. After the user custom enters a map scale, I need to be able to resize all the existing map features based on this scale.

What is the way to do this in OL 3? I've seen that in OL 2, there is a geometry.resize function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a StyleFunction.

Look at the following example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/vector-layer.html

If you zoom the map, you'll see the labels appear at a certain resolution.  This is controlled inside the style function.  Here's a snippet:

```
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    // === SEE THIS NEXT LINE ===
    var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
    if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
      highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f00',
          width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
          text: text,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#f00',
            width: 3
          })
        })
      })];
    }
    return highlightStyleCache[text];
  }
});
```

So you could define the size you want the features to have for any resolution range.  Note that the style property also applies to a `ol.layer.Vector`  layer.

Comment: Will this effect the extent of the features? I actually need to be able to get the exact size of the the features in meters which needs to match what the user expects based on the set scale.

Comment: The styling won't affect the size of the geometries.

Answer (score -1):

you can use API: `map.updateSize()`.

Reference: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#updateSize